# TCP slow start vs congestion avoidance when a packet is lost

Tags: algorithm, networking, tcp, protocols

I have recently been reading the 1988 paper on [Congestion Avoidance and Control](http://ee.lbl.gov/papers/congavoid.pdf), and it made an effort to differentiate slow-start from congestion avoidance.

However, there is one point which I did not understand, regarding which algorithm operates after a packet is lost.

- Based on the paper and [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_start) description of slow start, it wants TCP to start with a congestion window of size `1` after a loss event occurs.
- Based on congestion avoidance's [AIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_increase/multiplicative_decrease) algorithm, the congestion window should be halved after a packet loss.

Which algorithm will take precedence when a packet loss occurs? Will `cwnd` be set to `1` or to half its current size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the answer is in Appendix B of the same paper, which I had skipped earlier.

The combined algorithm actually maintains two state variables, a `cwnd` and an `ssthresh`.

When a time-out occurs due to a packet loss, the variable `ssthresh` is set to half the current the current window size, `cwnd` is set to 1, and then slow-start is used to reach that threshold (adding one to the window for every ACK received).

Once the threshold is reached, `cwnd` is incremented using Additive Increase (one increase for every full window of ACK) received.